# Page not found when refreshed on SailsJS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, sails.js

I'm buidling an app on sails and I am using it with angularjs. My problem is that everytime that I refresh a page it shows page not found. In apache I can fix it using this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.php/#/$1 
</IfModule>
```

How can I implement this on sails

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found that there's two ways of doing this.

**Single Entrypoint**

This method is much easier to maintain, but it may not work for everyone. If you have multiple angularjs apps, you will have to use the second method or a hybrid approach.

If you prefer to have a single angularjs entrypoint, and you're ok with it being in a subpath, its easy with the following setup:

In `config/routes.js` add the single catch-all route:

```
//wildcard catchall for angularjs entrypoint.
'/app/*': 'AngularController.index',
```

and have an angularJS app.js that looks like the following:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/app/user', {templateUrl: '/angular/application/views/settings/user.html', controller: 'settingsUserCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.when('/app/tags/:tagId', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/application/views/tags/tag.html',
        controller: 'tagListCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: true
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/app/user'});
    ...
}])
```

Now load a page on a browser that points to /app/anything. it loads the AngularJS index page, at which point the AngularJS ngRoute plugin loads the correct content.

**Multiple Entrypoint/Sails Controllers**

In `config/routes.js` you can add multiple routes, that match Sails Controllers, which will match AngularJS apps/controllers

```
'/user/*': 'UserController.index',
'/tag/*': 'TagController.index',
```

and use the following in your angular app.js

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/user', {templateUrl: '/angular/application/views/settings/user.html', controller: 'settingsUserCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.when('/tags/:tagId', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/application/views/tags/tag.html',
        controller: 'tagListCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: true
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/app/user'});
    ...
}])
```

Comment: But wouldn't this only render the AngularCOntroller with action index? How about the other routes with different controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have [a possible solution to this on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27715160/296829), basically a Sails controller version of the `mod_rewrite` snippet you posted.